# Wysiwyg for math equations

Tags: gratis, math, wysiwyg

I have a website for non-professional math users. I am looking for a WYSIWYG for math equations. I have found [wiris](http://www.wiris.com/) but it isn't free.

What I need:

- Simple, without programming knowledge (like MathML).
- Similar to [WolframAlpha equation input](http://www.wolframalpha.com/pro/#extended-keyboard) or the Wiris one.
- Real-time convertion to visual equations.
- Option to store the input in Latex.
- I have removed the Javascript restriction and I could accept any kind of webplugin that follow the previous bullets. (HTML5, java, Jquery etc)

Comment: You want this to be a JS based library to put into your website yes?

Comment: @NickWilde Exactly. I've added it tags.

Comment: Is jQuery required?

Comment: @unor Not necessarely. Anything that could be added in a website as a plugin. Like JS and JQuery.

Comment: @AnastasiosVentouris I'm thinking there probably isn't anything *quite* right. Could you email me? I have some thoughts that are too long for comment format and not really appropriate for an answer. My email is: design@briarmoon.ca

Answer (score 5):

You could use [MathJax](http://www.mathjax.org/).  It's a free, opensource, purely Javascript library for rendering math equations.  Stack Exchange uses it (that's how I heard of it).  It supports input through LaTeX and MathML according to it's site (I've only used the LaTeX input).  It looks like it has everything you want.

Comment: Thanks but I think the OP is looking for a WYSIWYG solution.

Comment: Missed that... He could always just make a MathJax preview like how SE does it. Like a side by side or a preview below.

Comment: Hmm I think it isn't what I am looking. I want a simple WYSIWYG for math input (like the one of WolframAlpha link) that will transform the input in LaTeX or MathML. So, a simple user without knowledge of LaTeX or MathML could write an equation and then store it in these forms.

Answer (score 2):

You can try [MathQuill](http://mathquill.com/) <sup>[1]</sup>, which isn't really a WYSIWYG editor but you can call it like a markdown editor, so say we use `*` to make the text italic like

```
*This will be italic on Stackoverflow*
```

Same way using MathQuill, say you want to make a fraction, of `3/4` so you can write it as

`\frac` and than type out the numbers, and switch the caret using arrow keys or say you want square root of `x` so you need to write

`\square` and than the `x`

<sup>[1] [Github Repo](https://github.com/mathquill/mathquill#readme)</sup>

---

You can also take a look at [FMatch](http://www.fmath.info/)  but personally I feel that will be a bit loaded, but you can give a shot

Comment: MathQuill is WYSIWYG. You do have to remember what keystrokes to use, e.g. ^ for superscript, _ for subscript.

Answer (score -1):

[TeXmacs](http://texmacs.org) is a very good editor suited for editing texts with mathematical formulas.

TeXmacs has import and export to LaTeX, but after exporting to LaTeX you need afterward to edit the LaTeX file manually, to insert all necessary macroses there.

I have written a book in TeXmacs (however it is somehow too slow for texts above 200 pages).

Comment: Thanks but I think the OP is looking for a JS based library to put into his website.